# How to discretize a sphere?

Tags: spheres, spherical-geometry, discrete-geometry, spherical-trigonometry, tessellations

I would like to discretize a sphere into icosahedra whose vertices are equidistant, i.e., I want to plot $n$ equidistant points on the surface of a sphere.

I am familiar with R, Python, and Matlab. Are there packages available to do this? Or are there scripts that I can run that have already been posted? Should I proceed with this problem doing spherical tessellation?

Comment: What do you mean by $n$ icosahedrons?

Comment: That is a good question. What I mean to say is that if I want- let's say- 300 points on the surface of a sphere equidistant apart, how can I find these?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9600801/6338725).

Comment: Obviously not every pair of points will be the same distance apart. If you want to partition a sphere into equilateral triangles, _one_ icosahedron inscribed inside the sphere will give you $12$ points. An octahedron will give you $6$ points. A tetrahedron will give you $4.$ For any other number of points you will have to settle for triangles that are only approximately equilateral.

Comment: A good simple approximation is to start with an icosahedron, then subdivide each face, for example by replacing each triangle with four smaller triangles. Normalize the points so that they lie on the sphere, then repeat as many times as you need.

Comment: All of your comments have been very helpful. I would look closer at the link provided by Rodrigo and let you know if I have any further questions. Thank you!

Comment: There is some discussion about this topic in [how to get $n$ equidistributed points on the unit sphre](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119329).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you want but Mathematica can do something close.

```
Needs["PolyhedronOperations`"]
G = Geodesate[PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "Faces"], 5] // N // Chop;
```

Here `G[[1]]` is a list of $265$ coordinates of the points of an order $5$ tessellation of an icosahedron, while `G[[2,1]]` is a list of $500$ triangle vertex indices from the list of $265$ points. For an order $n$ tessellation there are $\,15+10n^2\,$ vertices and $\,20n^2\,$ triangles.
Display the tessellated polyhedron using the command `Graphics3D[G]`.

As a check the first $4$ coordinates in `G[[1]]` is the following list:

```
{{0, 0, -0.951057}, {0, 0, 0.951057}, {-0.850651, 0, -0.425325}, {0.850651, 0, 0.425325}}
```

Also the first $6$ triangle tuples in `G[[2,1]]` is the following list:

```
{{14, 20, 15}, {15, 21, 16}, {16, 22, 17}, {17, 23, 18}, {18, 24, 19}, {20, 25, 21}}
```

Comment: It is great to see that it exists in such a compact form for Mathematica; however, I would prefer to do this in a software I have or can obtain for free. It seems that the "PolyhedronOperations" package simplifies the work. Do you know how I can find a similar package in R or Python? Thank you for your help thus far.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as shown. I am able to get a plot of the tesselated icosahedron, but G seems to return the 20 faces of the original icosahedron. Is there a way to extract the faces and vertices of the tesselated icosahedron?

Comment: @Botond I am sorry that it does not work for you. I just now used Mma 10.2 and 12.3 to verify that the two lines does what it is supposed to do. I also added a sentence about `Graphics3D[G]` to verify that it is tesselated.

Comment: @Somos, thank you for double checking. I'm using Mathematica 11.3.0.0 and G itself is just a 3x20 list of (presumably) vertex indices of the untesselated icosahedron. Graphics3D[G] returns an error because the index values are "not Graphics3D directives or primitives". I assume then that this is a version problem.